# Convert/migrate QGIS 2 Project to QGIS 3 Project automatically

Tags: qgis, convert, pyqgis-3, migration, batch

I have over 400 QGIS 2 projects.
I would like to automatically transfer these to QGIS3 projects.
Is there a tool for that?
Or suggestions for batch processing or Python?

Now I use Version 3.16, the old version is 2.18.

Comment: You may open older projects using QGIS 3. There might be some style and form issues, but nothing preventing the projects from working. Once you save the "old" projects using QGIS 3, they are up to date. That said, why do you feel the need to "transfer" the old projects? What do you expect to fail?

Comment: @Babel wait, you can do that? You can hand a project-file to a model and save it again?

Comment: @ Eric
My projects are working. 
I would like to save the storage space because the QGZ files are smaller.
I also have a uniform XML file structure in case I want to make changes to it.
And everything should be automated as far as possible.
@ babel
I thought in the models you can only control processing tools?

Answer (score 6):

Within QGIS, you can open your qgs files and save them as qgz

```py
# Here simple list of files but you can use:
# - `os.walk` from `os` module https://pymotw.com/3/os/,
# - `pathlib` module https://pymotw.com/3/pathlib/
# (need to transform the output path to a string)
# - `glob` https://pymotw.com/3/glob/
paths_qgs = ['/path/to/one.qgs', '/path/to/another.qgs']

for p in paths_qgs:
    QgsProject.instance().read(p)
    QgsProject.instance().write(p.replace('.qgs', '.qgz'))
```

You can also write from a `qgs` to `qgz`. A `qgz` is a `zip` file of a `qgs` with it extension renamed to `qgz`

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
from os.path import basename

paths_qgs = ['/path/to/one.qgs', '/path/to/another.qgs']

for p in paths_qgs:
    with ZipFile(p.replace('.qgs', '.qgz'), 'w') as myzip:
        myzip.write(p, basename(p))
```

Comment: The second worked very well for me. How can i get the first method to work? I was not able transform the paths to string.

Comment: I supposed you used `pathlib`. In this case, do `from pathlib import Path;p = Path('/path/to/projet.qgs');p = f"{p}"` The magic is in the f-Strings (learn more https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). In real case, `p` is not directly set like in my sample but from a loop to get all qgs files

Comment: @ ThomasG77
great, this is exactly what i was looking for.
Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Since `.qgz` files are simply zipped QGIS-project files, you may zip your files using the extension `.qgz` instead of `.zip` and will still be able to open them using QGIS 3.

I only tested this for a project prior saved in QGIS 3, so you probably will have to do some testing.

This still in manual work, but probably faster than opening each project and saving it from within QGIS.